# jQuery autosave running success function, but not updating MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My jQuery autosave is running the success function, but not updating the MySQL database.  What am I doing incorrectly?

**jQuery:**

```
function autosave() {
    var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000);

    var translation = $("#doc-translation").val();

    if (translation.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update-draft-submission.php",
            data: translation,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {   
                         $(".autosaved").empty().append("saved");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();
//retrieve our data
$iddoc = $_GET['iddoc'];
$trans = translation;
$transowner = $_SESSION['userid'];
$true = 1;
include "../dbconnect.php";
$query = "UPDATE translations
          SET trans='$trans'
          WHERE iddoc='$iddoc'
          AND transowner='$transowner'";
mysqli_query($query);
mysqli_close();

echo "Saved";
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error from the mysql query?  If not, then it's probably not affecting any rows.  Use mysqli_affected_rows or enter a test query directly into mysql.

Comment: Hmm.. I ran this in my SQL browser and it's getting an error on line 1:

`"UPDATE translations SET trans='lkjh'
WHERE iddoc='25'
AND transowner='hubrid'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not fetching the data in your PHP correctly:

```
$iddoc = $_GET['iddoc'];
$trans = translation;
```

- iddoc is not passed as a GET parameter anywhere
- "translation" is not a variable (neither do I think it is a constant)

Your SQL will break if it does not get the required values in the query.

Update your javascript so:

```
$.ajax(
 {
   type: "POST",
   url: "update-draft-submission.php",
   data: data: {translation:translation,iddoc:"XXX"},
   cache: false,
   success: function()
   {   
     $(".autosaved").empty().append("saved");
   }
 });
```

Replace **XXX** with your `iddoc` value.

Then in PHP fetch them as:

```
$iddoc = $_POST['iddoc'];
$trans = $_POST['translation'];
```

Comment: Isn't translation defined as the value of my textarea in my js?  If not, how can I pass it over?  I thought I was.

And iddoc is passed as a GET parameter in the URL?

Comment: I have updated the answer with code on how to pass the values in Javascript and how to fetch them in PHP

Comment: Great it works!  Just having trouble grabbing the iddoc from my URL in `,iddoc:"XXX"},` part.

Comment: the value of `XXX` *should not* be in quotes. It should be **XXX** not **"XXX"**. Also, do you mean you cannot get the value to replace inside XXX?

Comment: Exactly, I have a URL as follows: http://blahblah?id=XXX

I thought you could do $_GET['id'] or set it to a php variable $id and just stick it in the js?

Comment: Update the javascript line like this: `data: {translation:translation,iddoc:<?php echo $_GET['iddoc'];?>},`